# How to get Protractor's errors displayed when Jasmine times out?

Tags: jasmine, protractor

Here is my spec file:

```
fdescribe('My test', () => {

    beforeAll(async () => {
        await browser.get('/login');    // usually takes 10 sec.
        await LoginPo.login();          // usually takes 1  sec.
        await browser.wait(protractor.ExpectedConditions.urlIs('myurl'), 15000);
    }, 20000);

    afterAll(async () => {
        await element(by.id('wrongID')).click();
    });

    it('dummy test ok', async () => {
        await expect(true).toBeTruthy();
    });
});
```

And a part of my config file:

```
exports.config = {
    allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
    jasmineNodeOpts: {
        defaultTimeoutInterval: 5000
    },
    SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false }
```

With this config I get an output with a Jasmine timeout, with no further relevant information:

```
Jasmine started

  My test
    √ dummy test ok
    × My test
      - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
          at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
          at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)

**************************************************
*                     Errors                     *
**************************************************

1) My test
  - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.

Executed 1 of 111 specs (1 ERROR) (110 SKIPPED) in 14 secs.
(node:9608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: 'fail' was used when there was no current spec, this could be because an asynchronous test timed out
    at Env.fail (C:\workspace\mdib\node_modules\jasmine\node_modules\jasmine-core\lib\jasmine-core\jasmine.js:1270:15)
    (...)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
(node:9608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9608) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Now if I remove the specific Jasmine timeout of `20000` msec in my `beforeAll()`, I get this output:

```
Jasmine started

  My test
    × 1 - dummy test ok
      - Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
          at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
          at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    × My test
      - Failed: No element found using locator: By(id, wrongID)
          at elementArrayFinder.getWebElements.then (C:\workspace\mdib\node_modules\protractor\built\element.js:814:27)
          at <anonymous>
          at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
      From asynchronous test:
          (...)
```

It includes the info I need from Protractor (wrong ID) but the dummy test has failed and it also includes a Jasmine timeout because the app loading takes more than the `5000` msec defined by `defaultTimeoutInterval`.

I assume that, when I set the `20000` msec jasmine timeout, Protractor fails and the test never finishes and that's why Jasmine times out, hiding relevant Protractor error log.

How could I get this useful Protractor error log without the Jasmine timeout ?

Using `jasmine 3.3.0` and `protractor 5.4.1`.

Comment: It's my understanding that the way to get the error messages you want you have to wrap all the awaited commands in a try/catch. Then you can dump the stacktrace to the console. That is apparently the proper way to do it. I don't do that so I can't say for sure that it works but I have seen conversations about this exact topic several times and that is the fix people suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I think Increasing your defaultTimeoutInterval will solve the problem:

```
exports.config = {
allScriptsTimeout: 11000,
jasmineNodeOpts: {
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 40000
},
SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false }
```

Comment: Doesn't work. Protractor timeout occurs (`11000` msec) and no info about the wrong id.

Comment: @Coli: did you find a solution? I have similar issue.

Comment: Nope, no clean solution so far.